# Languages for developing applications for Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I Need to know how can i develop an application for **Microsoft Surface Tablet**
and if there are many option which is the best ?
Is the best to use **C#** or **Silverlight** ? **OR** there are any other ways?!

What is the best way from :
-Scalability
-Time consuming
-Powerflite
-Writability
-Reusability

Comment: Silverlight isn't a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target all versions of the surface tablet, you'll need to develop against the [Windows API for Windows Store Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx).  This can be done via JavaScript, C#, Visual Basic, and C++.

The design of the API is such that all four options should perform reasonably well.  That being said, C++ does provide a bit more control (as you handle the memory a bit more directly - similar to COM), so would potentially provide the greatest control over your criteria.  However, for many applications, any of the above languages would be sufficient, given the design of the framework and libraries.